# POST request on button click

Tags: html, css, node.js, post, button

```
<form action="shorturl" method="POST">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="https://">
    <a class="search-btn">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-minimize"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

I made a button in CSS out of the  tag, but for some reason, when I click on it, I can't get a post request.

I tried this

```
<a class="search-btn" action="shorturl" formmethod="POST">
```

but nothing

and this

```
<a class="search-btn" href="shorturl" formmethod="POST">
```

which gives a get request

Comment: Have you try with `<button type="submit">` instead of `a`?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `formmethod` attribute on the  tag, the form must be submitted using `<button type="submit">`. (If JavaScript is not used)

```html
<form action="shorturl" method="POST">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="https://">
    <button class="search-btn" type="submit">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-minimize"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Or if you use JavaScript:

```html
<form action="shorturl" method="POST" id="searchForm">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="https://">
    <a class="search-btn" id="searchBtn">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-minimize"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
document.getElementById("searchBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("searchForm".submit();
});
```